# Where are the headers of libavcodec and libavformat located?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

After executing the following commands in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev
```

I tried to find the headers (various `#include<libavcodec/*.h>`) in the `/usr/include` directory, but the header files do not seem to be there.

Where are the headers located? Should I compile the source code for FFMPEG to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are located in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec`. A simple `sudo find / -name "libavcodec"`would have revealed this.

The packages i have installed are:

```
libavutil-dev:amd64 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
libswresample-dev:amd64 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
libavcodec-dev:amd64 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
libavformat-dev:amd64 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
```

Comment: What package did you install for the headers? I did not find a folder named `libavcodec` inside `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Comment: I only installed the two you mentioned via synaptic.